# how to solve a warning problem with Nextjs, react-quilljs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, quill

I am using react-quilljs in my project and the truth is that it works well for me, except that when I open the browser I get some warnings that I would like to resolve so that everything works as it should.

[image]

I have added those external modules to the react-quilljs package which fulfill their function which adds the indicated functionality, but again I say that I would like those warnings not to appear and I would also like to know what causes this problem to better understand its operation.
I will add the implementation code so you can tell me where I made a mistake.

```
import { useQuill } from "react-quilljs";
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import { useEffect, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from "react";

function GenericTextEditor({ setHtml }, ref) {
  const theme = "snow";
  const placeholder = "Write here...";

  const modules = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
      [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }],
      ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
      [{ align: [] }],
      [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
      [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
      [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }],
      ["link", "image", "video"],
      ["clean"],
    ],
    imageResize: true,
    imageDrop: true,
    magicUrl: true,
    clipboard: {
      matchVisual: false,
    },
  };

  const formats = [
    "header",
    "size",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strike",
    "blockquote",
    "align",
    "color",
    "background",
    "list",
    "ordered",
    "bullet",
    "indent",
    "link",
    "image",
    "video",
    "clean",
  ];

  const { quill, quillRef, Quill } = useQuill({
    theme,
    modules,
    formats,
    placeholder,
  });

  if (Quill && !quill) {
    const ImageResize = require("quill-image-resize").default;
    const ImageDrop = require("quill-image-drop-module").ImageDrop;
    const MagicUrl = require("quill-magic-url").default;
    Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize);
    Quill.register("modules/imageDrop", ImageDrop);
    Quill.register("modules/magicUrl", MagicUrl);
  }

  const clearTextContent = () => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML("");
    }
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    clearText: clearTextContent,
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.on("text-change", (delta, oldDelta, source) => {
        setHtml(quillRef.current.firstChild.innerHTML);
      });
    }
  }, [quill, quillRef, setHtml]);

  return (
    <div id="text-editor">
      <div ref={quillRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default forwardRef(GenericTextEditor)
```

Thank you in advance for your help